# Mongodb query using Spring Data does not add limit in the query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

So I am trying to do a mongodb query using Spring data with limit attached. I have noticed that Spring data doesn't add limit to the query itself, but rather gets all data, performs limit on it on Java side then returns limited result. Is this true or am I doing something wrong in my code here.

```
Criteria criteria = queryBuilder.getQuery(searchCriteria);
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        query.limit(500);
        logger.Debug("Query: " + query);
        if (query.getQueryObject() != null){
            resultSet = (List<T>) _mongoDb.find(query, model.getClass(), _collectionName);

        }
```

The query I see in the log is this:

```
Query: Query: { "$or" : [ { "PARTY" : { "$elemMatch" : { "PARTY_ID" : "32135"}}} , { "ABBR_NUM" : "6873"} , { "ANN_ABBR_NUM" : "6873"}]}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

I don't see a limit of 500 attached to this query. Is there something I have missed? By the way, the fields in the query are part of "searchCriteria" passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Your log statement is just logging the query. Behind the scenes the limit actually gets applied to the cursor, so you're not going to see it using that log statement.

Try [using the MongoDB profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) (set profile level 2) then query the system.profile collection and you will see that your limit is actually applied to the query, indicated by the `ntoreturn` field in the profile record.